# Efficient Way to store a table of checkbox data into MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

[image: Table format]

I have a table of data which consist of checkboxes and I want to find an efficient way to store it into MySQL database. For now, the HTML is like below

```
<tr class="weekpattern">
            <th class="collabel tlc"></th>
            <th class="collabel">1</th>
            <th class="collabel">2</th>
            <th class="collabel">3</th>
            <th class="collabel">4</th>
            <th class="collabel">5</th>
            <th class="collabel">6</th>
            <th class="collabel trc">7</th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="weekpattern">
            <th class="rowlabel" shift="a"> A </th>
            <td align="center" valign="middle"><input type="checkbox"  shift="a"  value="1" name="a1"></td>
            <td align="center" valign="middle"><input type="checkbox"  shift="a"  value="1" name="a2"></td>
            <td align="center" valign="middle"><input type="checkbox"  shift="a"  value="1" name="a3"></td>
            <td align="center" valign="middle"><input type="checkbox"  shift="a"  value="1" name="a4"></td>
            <td align="center" valign="middle"><input type="checkbox"  shift="a"  value="1" name="a5"></td>
            <td align="center" valign="middle"><input type="checkbox"  shift="a"  value="1" name="a6"></td>
            <td align="center" valign="middle"><input type="checkbox"  shift="a"  value="1" name="a7"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="weekpattern">
            <th class="rowlabel"> B </th>
            <td align="center" valign="middle"><input type="checkbox"   value="1" name="b1"></td>
            <td align="center" valign="middle"><input type="checkbox"   value="1" name="b2"></td>
            <td align="center" valign="middle"><input type="checkbox"   value="1" name="b3"></td>
            <td align="center" valign="middle"><input type="checkbox"   value="1" name="b4"></td>
            <td align="center" valign="middle"><input type="checkbox"   value="1" name="b5"></td>...
```

Which means I will have to repeat the codes below several times:

```
$_SESSION['a1'] = $_POST['a1'];
    $_SESSION['a2'] = $_POST['a2'];
    $_SESSION['a3'] = $_POST['a3'];
    $_SESSION['a4'] = $_POST['a4'];
    $_SESSION['a5'] = $_POST['a5'];
    $_SESSION['a6'] = $_POST['a6'];...
```

Is there a better way to store the values into a mysql database?

Comment: Why on earth do you want to store this in session ?

Comment: you ask for an advice for php part or mysql structure?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

'Efficient' is a slightly ambiguous term. In terms of storage requirements, the most efficient solution would be a bit-field - but that will result in *very* inefficient queries - and will be difficult to adapt to changes in the data model. If it were me I'd just normalise it:

```
CREATE TABLE responses (
   respondent_id INTEGER NOT NULL, /* to reference the set of answers */
   row_id VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL,
   col_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
   response ENUM ('NO', 'YES') NOT NULL
   PRIMARY KEY (respondent_id, row_id, col_id)
);
```

I'd also use a nested array to emulate a multidimensional array in PHP:

```
$rows=array('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'); 
for ($y=0; $y<7; $y++) {
   print "<tr>\n";
   for ($x=1; $x<=7; $x++) {
     print "<td><input type='checkbox' name='box[$x][$y]'></td>\n";
   }
   print "</tr>\n";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use as a serialize or JSON like `{a1:0, a2:1,a3:0}`
.when select this data ..decode it again...
I prefer this way...